# Compare 2 Excel Files and output the difference only (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare 2 XLXS and I would like to output the difference only. Can this be done with Compare-Object?

I currently am using this script which works, but it does not capture what I exactly need:

```
#IMPORT PS EXCEL MODULE 
import-module psexcel
#FILE TO BE COMPARED VARIABLES
$file1 = Import-XLSX C:\CurrentFile.xlsx
$file2 = Import-XLSX C:\PreviousFile.xlsx

#FILTER TO GET DATA ONLY FROM THE REFERENCE FILE ONLY
filter leftside{
param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [PSCustomObject]
        $obj
    )

    $obj|?{$_.sideindicator -eq '<='}
}

#PROPERTY VARIABLE
$property = "Name" , "UserPrincipalName" , "NickName" , "Age" , "Sex"

#COMPARISON PROPER
$Comparison = Compare-Object -referenceobject $file1 -differenceobject $file2 -SyncWindow ($file1.Length / 2) -property $property | leftside
```

Here is how the sample files look like:

```
PreviousFile:

Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20  M
UserUser 2  User2@old.com       User2       20  M
UserUser 3  User3@old.com       User3       20  M
UserUser 4  User4@old.com       User90      20  M
UserUser 5  User5@old.com       User91      20  M

CurrentFile:

Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20  M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20  M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20  M
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User4       20  M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5       20  M
```

DIfferences:All items under UserPrincipalName except User1@user.com

UnderNickname User90-User4 , User91-User5

Output with the current script:

Output shows the complete info on rows that has differences.

```
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20  M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20  M
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User4       20  M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5       20  M
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6       20  M
```

Expected output:

```
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 1              
UserUser 2  User2@user.com                  
UserUser 3  User3@user.com                  
UserUser 4  User4@user.com                  
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5           
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6
```

I would like the script to output my identifier all the time, in this case "Name" I also would want it to output the Difference only. If any changes are found between old and current file, display the current file that has found differences only.

Is there a way to output it this way?

Any help, any assistance, will be really appreciated. Thank you!

---

After further analysis. I may have messed up on my example.
It is true that I need my identifier to output everytime. But I need it to output on entries that has differences **only** even if my identifier is not changed.

Here is a new example:

```
PreviousFile:

Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20  M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20  F
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      UserC       20  M
UserUser 4  User4@old.com       User4       20  M
UserUser 5  User5@old.com       User5       20  M

CurrentFile:

Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20  M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20  M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20  M
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User4       20  M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5       20  M
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6       20  M




Expected output:

Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age Sex             
UserUser 2                                      F
UserUser 3                      UserC  
UserUser 4  User4@user.com                  
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6       20  M
```

UserUser1 has no entries at all, because everything matches

UserUser2 has appeared on the list because the gender changed to F

UserUser3, has UserC for nickname

UserUser4 and 5 has the updated @user.com on user principal name

Useruser6 is a new object

all entries that has any difference will display the identifier 'Name' and the difference only.

I have tried playing with your code a bit, but I could not get this output. To be honest, I don't understand everything happening in your script, yet.

I hope you can help me out with this one, too.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

For these more customized compare outputs I suggest ditching `Compare-Object` and going freestyle in order to control exactly what you want.

Once we determine how we want to match records between the two datasets we can loop through each property of the current objects and compare them to the same property of the matched object in the previous file.  If the values match then we should output an empty string.  If they do not match, they we should output the value of the current object.  We will always output the value of the property we choose to match on which in this case is the 'Name' property.

```
# TEST DATA
$previousFile = @'
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age  Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20   M
UserUser 2  User2@old.com       User2       20   M
UserUser 3  User3@old.com       User3       20   M
UserUser 4  User4@old.com       User90      20   M
UserUser 5  User5@old.com       User91      20   M
'@

$currentFile = @'
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age  Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20   M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20   M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20   M
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User4       20   M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5       20   M
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6       20   M
'@

$previous = $previousFile -replace ' {2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$current = $currentFile -replace ' {2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
# END TEST DATA

# Set which property should be used to match records from current to previous
$matchPropertyName = 'Name'

$current | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = $_
    $match = $previous.where({ $_.$matchPropertyName -eq $obj.$matchPropertyName })
    if ($match) {
        $out = [ordered]@{}

        # loop through all the properties in current objects to determine whether to show them or not
        $obj.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            # if property = 'Name' then include the value as record Identifier
            if ($_.Name -eq $matchPropertyName) { $out[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

            # else if value of property in current matches previous set value to empty string
            elseif ($_.Value -eq $match[0].($_.Name)) {
                $out[$_.Name] = ''
            }

            # else current value does not match previous value so output current value
            else {
                $out[$_.Name] = $_.Value
            }
        }
        [pscustomobject]$out
    }

    # if not matched by 'Name' property then consider as new object and output all values
    else {
        $obj
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name       UserPrincipalName NickName Age Sex
----       ----------------- -------- --- ---
UserUser 1
UserUser 2 User2@user.com
UserUser 3 User3@user.com
UserUser 4 User4@user.com    User4        
UserUser 5 User5@user.com    User5
UserUser 6 User6@user.com    User6    20  M
```

One thing to note about this solution is it does not account for lines that have been removed (i.e., lines that existed in previous but have been removed in current), though this appears to be what you were going for in your own example by filtering for only the leftside.

---

### UPDATE

In response to your additional information, here is an updated solution  which does not include unchanged records and includes more detail to hopefully help you understand better what is happening.  To not output unchanged objects, when looping through and comparing the objects we can keep track of whether an object has changed in a variable and then only output the object if we know there were changes.

```
# TEST DATA
$previousFile = @'
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age  Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20   M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20   M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20   M
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User4       20   M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User5       20   M
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User6       20   M
'@

$currentFile = @'
Name        UserPrincipalName   NickName    Age  Sex
UserUser 1  User1@user.com      User1       20   M
UserUser 2  User2@user.com      User2       20   M
UserUser 3  User3@user.com      User3       20   F
UserUser 4  User4@user.com      User_4       20   M
UserUser 5  User5@user.com      User_5       20   M
UserUser 6  User6@user.com      User_6       30   M
'@

$previous = $previousFile -replace ' {2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$current = $currentFile -replace ' {2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
# END TEST DATA

# Set which property should be used to match records from current to previous
$matchPropertyName = 'Name'

$current | ForEach-Object {
    # in ForEach-Object scriptblock $_ is the current object being processed.
    # Below we assign $_ to $obj in order to reference it in the
    # $previous.where({}) scriptblock where $_ will reference it's own object
    # from the $previous array
    $obj = $_

    # Here we are looking for an object in $previous array where property $matchPropertyName, which we have
    # defined earlier as being equal to 'Name', matches our current object's 'Name' property.  We stick this match
    # in a variable called $match
    $match = $previous.where({ $_.$matchPropertyName -eq $obj.$matchPropertyName })

    # if we find a matching record in $previous
    if ($match) {
        # We will use $isModified to keep track of whether a changes was found in any of the properties
        $isModified = $false

        # create an ordereddictionary in which to build our own object with
        # we use this to capture the property names and values using key-value pairs
        # $out[<keyname>] = <value>
        # later we can easily convert this to an object using the [pscustomobject] type accelerator
        $out = [ordered]@{}

        # Loop through all the properties in current object to determine whether to show them or not.
        # Here we use the an intrinsic member called .psobject to access a collection containing all
        # the object's properties and values and loop through each of them.
        # i.e., we loop through objects that look like this
        #
        # Name              Value
        # ----              -----
        # Name              UserUser 1
        # UserPrincipalName User1@user.com
        # NickName          User1
        # Age               20
        # Sex               M   
        
        # there are 5 properties so we will be looping 5 times in the following ForEach-Object call, 
        # once for each property of the current object
        $obj.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            # if property = 'Name' then include the value as record Identifier
            if ($_.Name -eq $matchPropertyName) { $out[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

            # else if value of property in current matches previous set value to empty string
            elseif ($_.Value -eq $match[0].($_.Name)) {
                $out[$_.Name] = ''
            }

            # else current value does not match previous value so output current value
            else {
                # create a key-value pair in our dictionary containing the property name and value
                # e.g., $out['NickName'] = 'User1'
                $out[$_.Name] = $_.Value

                # update $isModified to true so we know to include in the output
                $isModified = $true
            }
        }

        # Check if the object has been modified and if so, output it.
        # We use the [pscustomobject] type accelerator here to convert our ordereddictionary to an object
        # containing our key-value pairs as properties.
        if ($isModified) { [pscustomobject]$out }
    }

    # if we don't find a matching object in $previous then consider as new object and output all values
    else {
        $obj
    }
}
```

References:

- [.psobject intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2#remove-properties)
- [[pscustomobject] type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2#converting-a-hashtable)
- [[ordered] type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2#ordered-hashtables)

Comment: Hello Daniel!

I could not find the words to show how thankful I am with your solution. This is the answer that I am looking for. 

Thank you so much!

I am just wondering, on which part of this script were you able to display all the 'name' entries?

I will study your script, and thank god for your wonderful brain sir.



Stay safe!

Comment: I made a mistake. My output will not work on the set of data that I am trying to capture.
:( I posted an 'answer' with additional information. I know I am pushing my luck, but I hope you can check it out, too. In any case, thank you again for helping!!!

Comment: @bujom, you're welcome and no worries!  Please see the update at the bottom of my previous answer.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!!!

I have tried running it and it is exactly what I described. Also thank you for putting the extra effort to write the comments. You saved me another whole day of searching for answers. Again, thank you sir. May god bless you, or if you don't believe in that kind of stuff, may you have goodluck on all your endeavors!

Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!