# Compare Web Application configuration keys as in 2 arrays and display the difference

Tags: powershell

I know similar questions has been asked several times, I have tried the suggested answers but I am not getting the answer that I require.

```
$config = az webapp config appsettings list --name 'xx' --resource-group 'xxxx' | ConvertFrom-Json
$incomplete = $config | Select-Object -Property name


$config = az webapp config appsettings list --name 'xx' --resource-group 'xxxxx' | ConvertFrom-Json
$complete = $config | Select-Object -Property name
```

A lot of the answers that I have seen on SO, they suggest using the below.

```
compare-object $complete $incomplete
$complete | Where {$incomplete -NotContains $_}
```

Lets assume $complete has the following values `A,B,C,D` and $incomplete has `C,D`. I only need the script to print out `A,B`. I am currently using vlookups in excel to compare and highlight the differences and I am thinking there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552279/11954025) and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If `$incomplete` is a *subset* of `$complete`, all you need is [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)'s `-PassThru` switch, which passes the differing elements through as-is (albeit *decorated* with a `SideIndicator` property), so that the resulting elements are by definition those unique to `$complete`:

```bash
$complete = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
$incomplete = 'C', 'D'

# -> 'A', 'B'
Compare-Object $complete $incomplete -PassThru
```